# Is there a way to specify a year range for filtering or sorting an array?

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays, one array is milestoneyears which is used for displaying  its contents on a webpage and is also used for iterating through a secondary array which is comprised of milestones, each milestone has a date and milestoneyears is used to select milestones from year ranges of say 1980-1990.

I am not able to display the milestones within a range from milestoneyears currently, only those whose years match the milestoneyears value.

I have tried to modify my conditional to only display milestones from a specific range.

```
<div id="output"></div>

var milestoneyears = ['1980', '1990','1999','2000', '2001']

var jsonData = {
    "milestones" : [
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1980",
            "title": "First title for 1980 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1980",
            "title": "Second title for 1980 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1982",
            "title": "First title for 1982 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1990",
            "title": "First title for 1990 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1999",
            "title": "First title for 1999 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1999",
            "title": "Second title for 1999 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1999",
            "title": "Third title for 1999 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "2000",
            "title": "First title for 2000 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "2001",
            "title": "First title for 2000 event"
        }
      ]
 }


var menu = $("#output");

// FIND DIFFERENCE IN ARRAYS
function arrDiff(arr1, arr2) {
    var arrays = [arr1, arr2].sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length);
    var smallSet = new Set(arrays[0]);
    return arrays[1].filter(x => !smallSet.has(x));
}

var foundArr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < milestoneyears.length; i++) {
    var catz = milestoneyears[i];
    for(var x = 0; x < jsonData.milestones.length; x++) {
        if(catz == jsonData.milestones[x].milestoneDate) {
            foundArr.push(catz)
        }
    }
}

var filteredArr = foundArr.filter(function(item, index) {
  if (foundArr.indexOf(item) == index)
    return item;
});

var noMilestones = arrDiff(filteredArr, milestoneyears);

$.each(milestoneyears, function(catIndex, category) {

  // DOM ELEMENTS
  var $item = $('<div>').addClass('navContainer');
  var $title = $('<div>').addClass('title').appendTo($item);
  var $links = $('<ul>').appendTo(
    $('<div>').addClass('links').appendTo($item)
  );

  // MILESTONE YEAR
  $title.text(category);

  $.each(jsonData.milestones, function(linkIndex, link) {
        console.log("milestone: " + link.milestoneDate + link.title)
    var $link = $('<a>');

    if (link.milestoneDate.indexOf(category) != -1) {
        console.log("years: " + link.milestoneDate)

        $link.attr('href', link.Link)
          .text(link.milestoneDate + "--" + link.title)
          .appendTo($('<li>').appendTo($links));

    }

   if(noMilestones.indexOf(category) != -1) {
        $link.attr('href', "#")
          .text("No milestones currently for this category")
          .appendTo($('<li>').appendTo($links));
            return false;
   }

  }) 

  // DISPLAY TO CONTAINER
  $item.appendTo(menu);
})
```

Expecting to show milestones 1980, 1980 and 1980 under the milestoneyear for 1980. Currently it is only showing milestones who's year's exactly match milestoneyears array values.

```
 1980
  * 1980
  * 1980
  * 1982
 1990
  * 1990
  * 1999
  * 1999
  * 1999
 2000
  * 2001
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the beginning of the `$.each` callback I'd convert `category` to number and also grab the one after it, if any:

```
category = +category;
nextCategory = +(milestoneyears[cateIndex + 1] || "9999");
```

then instead of

```
if (link.milestoneDate.indexOf(category) != -1) {
```

I'd convert `link.milestoneDate` to number and do a range check:

```
var thisDate = +link.milestoneDate;
if (thisDate >= category && thisDate < nextCategory) {
```

That checks to see if it's within the range `category <= thisDate < nextCategory`.

Warning: The exact solution above fails after the year 9999. Adjust as appropriate, should the need arise.

---

(You don't strictly need to convert to number, because all of your dates are four digits and so comparing the strings will still compare them correctly. To me it feels more correct to use numbers, but...)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce

1. Loop through milestone years with reduce with decade starting year
2. Filter values comparing with that decade

```js
var milestoneyears = ['1980', '1990','1999','2000', '2001']

var jsonData = {
    "milestones" : [
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1980",
            "title": "First title for 1980 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1980",
            "title": "Second title for 1980 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1982",
            "title": "First title for 1982 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1990",
            "title": "First title for 1990 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1999",
            "title": "First title for 1999 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1999",
            "title": "Second title for 1999 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "1999",
            "title": "Third title for 1999 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "2000",
            "title": "First title for 2000 event"
        },
        {
            "milestoneDate": "2001",
            "title": "First title for 2000 event"
        }
      ]
 }

console.log(milestoneyears.reduce((acc, v) => {
  acc[(Math.floor(v/10)*10)] = jsonData.milestones.filter(val => {
    return val.milestoneDate >= (Math.floor(v/10)*10) && val.milestoneDate < (Math.floor(v/10) *10)+10
  });
  return acc
}, {}))
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ewmayW?editors=1010